# How can I use Reactive Extensions to throttle SearchPane.SuggestionsRequested?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, system.reactive

Reactive Extensions allow me to "observe" a stream of events. For example, when the user is typing their search query in the Windows 8 Search Pane, SuggestionsRequested is raised over and over (for each letter). How can I leverage Reactive Extensions to throttle the requests?

Something like this:

```
SearchPane.GetForCurrentView().SuggestionsRequested += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.QueryText.Length < 3)
        return;
    // TODO: if identical to the last request, return;
    // TODO: if asked less than 500ms ago, return;
};
```

**Solution**

```
System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.FromEventPattern<Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchPaneSuggestionsRequestedEventArgs>
    (Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchPane.GetForCurrentView(), "SuggestionsRequested")
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.CurrentThread)
    .Where(x => x.EventArgs.QueryText.Length > 3)
    .DistinctUntilChanged(x => x.EventArgs.QueryText.Trim())
    .Subscribe(x => HandleSuggestions(x.EventArgs));
```

Install RX for WinRT: http://nuget.org/packages/Rx-WinRT/
Learn more: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/08/15/reactive-extensions-v2-0-has-arrived.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [`Throttle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211682%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and [`DistinctUntilChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.distinctuntilchanged%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) methods.

```
System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.FromEventPattern<Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchPaneSuggestionsRequestedEventArgs>
    (Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchPane.GetForCurrentView(), "SuggestionsRequested")
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.CurrentThread)
    .Where(x => x.EventArgs.QueryText.Length > 3)
    .DistinctUntilChanged(x => x.EventArgs.QueryText.Trim())
    .Subscribe(x => HandleSuggestions(x.EventArgs));
```

You might want/need to use different overload for `DistinctUntilChanged`, e.g. using different equality comparer or the `Func<TSource, TKey>` overload:

```
.DistinctUntilChanged(e => e.QueryText.Trim())
```

That will do what you want.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT Oh, sorry for that :) It popped up when I was browsing... Glad I was right though.